# How to fix a "hex string of odd length" error

Tags: go, go-ethereum, geth, binance-smart-chain

I'm trying to write a script in Go to interact with a smart contract on Binance Smart Chain using an RPC and the `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum` package. However, I keep getting "panic: hex string of odd length" when trying to call a method involving a `bind.TransactOpts` struct. Here's the relevant code:

```
secret_key := "<my_secret_key>"
sk, _ := crypto.HexToECDSA(secret_key)

wallet_addr := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(sk.PublicKey)

auth, _ := bind.NewKeyedTransactorWithChainID(sk, big.NewInt(56))

...

tx := &bind.TransactOpts{
        From:      wallet_addr,
        Nonce:     nil,
        Signer:    auth.Signer,
        Value:     min_bet,
        GasPrice:  nil,
        GasFeeCap: nil,
        GasTipCap: nil,
    }
    
attempt, err := instance.BetBull(tx, epoch)
if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
fmt.Println(attempt)
```

The problem seems to me to be with the `Signer` field of `tx`. When I run `fmt.Println(auth.Signer)` the output is `0x4341680`, which has 9 characters. I'm new to coding and just doing this for fun, so it's likely that I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have a hexadecimal representation of a number  instead of a sequence of bytes encoded to hex. The decoder is looking for the latter.   Where did the data come from? What is decoding it?

Comment: @Zombo the auth.Signer is a github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind SignerFn. i'm not sure what's decoding it. i am assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that the hex value is the memory address for the signer function. i tried using a sequence of bytes encoded to a hex "0x04341680" but it won't compile because the field has to be of type bind.SignerFn. i'm not sure what's decoding it - the documentation is pretty complicated, but hopefully i'll figure it out. in any case, thank you.

Comment: What line is panicing?  Include the error message verbatim.